# Facing errors with string items merged with brackets and percentage

Tags: python-3.x

I created list with the following items:

```
x=['RX', '0(', '0%)', '2(', '0%)', '154018(', '99%)', '0(', '0%)', '0(', '0%)', '0(', '0%)']
```

I want to get as:

```
y=[0,2,154018,0,0,0]
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to parse the elements of your list to `int` after stripping `(` and add them to a new list:

```
x=['RX', '0(', '0%)', '2(', '0%)', '154018(', '99%)', '0(', '0%)', '0(', '0%)', '0(', '0%)']
y = []
for a in x:
   try:
      y.append(int(a.strip('(')))
   except:
      continue
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 154018, 0, 0, 0]
```